Error messages by starting or ending the standby mode
I am new in using Linux and use Ubuntu Studio 24.10. When I start the or end the standby mode the system shows an black screen with error messages for a very short time before turning display of or switching to to login screen. It is such a short time that I only can read something about "failed". Each time the list with messages becomes longer until I restart the System. My Question is: Where are these messages stored so I can read and analyze it and solve the problem.

This question is similar to: Where can I find the boot log?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

System messages are accessible with the journalctl command. So right after a resume, something like
sudo journalctl --since "5 minutes ago"

should give you a hint as to what is going on.
